# Joomla recaptcha issues

Tags: joomla, recaptcha

I have a Joomla site that features a recaptcha v3 check on some forms. Whenever the recaptcha is executed, it errors and doesn't provide a valid recaptcha token, any help will be greatly appreciated

At the moment, I am trying to do this:

```
grecaptcha.execute("SECRET_KEY", {action: 'submit'}).then(function(token){
    console.log(token);
});
```

It works fine outside of Joomla with the same credentials, but when inside of Joomla, it causes errors

Answer (score 1):

check if mootools is active in the page and remove it. There is an issue with recaptcha and mootools